# Return a list into a table form based on dropdown selection MVC C# in the same view

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, css-tables

My List that should return a table based on what the ID in the dropdown selected was.

Controller:

```
    public List<tblResults> GetResult(int Id)
    {            
            var v = (from a in entities.tblResults
                     where
                     a.result_id == Id
                     select a);
            return v.ToList();                      
    }
```

My view that is the issue currently.

```
      @if (ViewBag.Result != null)
      {
          @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.maindropdown, new SelectList(ViewBag.ResultGroup, "id", "mainvalues"), "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" })


                        }
                        <div id="showorhide"> 
                      <table class="table table-striped" style="width:85%" align="center"> 
                         <tr>                            
                            @foreach (var item in ViewBag.GetResult)
                            {
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.result_id)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
                        </td>
                        </tr></table>
                            }
                    </div>
```

JS code that trigger the table :

```
    $("#dropdown").change(function () {            
        if ($(this).val() == "Please Select") {
            $("#showorhide").hide();
        }
        else {
            var selectedValue = this.value;
            $.get('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', { id: selectedValue }, function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $("#showorhide").html(result);
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You send your ajax request to `GetProduct` but your action is `GetResult` so you send your data wrong place. I tidy up your code little bit. Your data is not coming because `ViewBag.GetResult` is empty and you try to append json result as html. So you need to get result and append as table element every result item. And make sure your `GetResult` returning some values.

controller:

```
public JsonResult GetResult(int Id)
    {            
            var v = (from a in entities.tblResults
                     where
                     a.result_id == Id
                     select a);
            return Json(v, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                    
    }
```

view:

```
@if (ViewBag.Result != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.maindropdown, new SelectList(ViewBag.ResultGroup, "id", "mainvalues"), "Please Select", new{ @class = "form-control", @id = "dropdown" })
}
<div id="showorhide">
    <table class="table table-striped" style="width:85%" align="center" id="resultTable">
        @foreach (var item in ViewBag.GetResult)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.result_id)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

js:

```
$("#dropdown").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == "Please Select") {
        $("#showorhide").hide();
    }
    else {
        var selectedValue = this.value;
        $.get('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', { id: selectedValue }, function (result) {
            if (result) {
                for (let index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                    const e = result[index];
                    $("#resultTable").append("<tr><td>" + e.result_id + "</td><td>" + e.name + "</td></tr>");
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Onur, thanks. One more question as I see my GetResult is not returning anything because its not getting the selected ID from the dropdown. $.get('@Url.Action("GetResult", "Home")', { id: selectedValue },  This is supposed to send it to the code in the Controller, correct? public List<tblResults> GetResult(int Id) This is suppose to  then return the results? but it does not.

Comment: Do you have dropdown more than one has id is dropdown or does your dropdown has values in items. Maybe it's because your dropdown option doesn't have any value. If it's not the problem console log your selected value and change controller parameter to int id and change var selectedValue = this.value; to var selectedValue = $(this).val();

Comment: this is the result if I debug the javascript code.     result: System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project.Models.GetResult]

Comment: You need to cast it to json result I will edit my answer